# What are the traits of and how could a compound(mosquito) eye be used for bug-sized equipment

Tags: materials, alternate-earth, tools

How could a medieval nomadic explorer air-ship (bug-sized people) use the African mosquito's eyes for equipment building? there is no magic in their world apart from the fact that such a tiny species could build tools. By the way, they travel through the savannah at approximately 10m above ground and there are no humans.
(Second question; improvements and criticism will be received well)

Edit:
These people will cut the eyes using hand saws and then remove the excess flesh using knives. They (adults, children are usually 0.5) are 0.6 to 0.9 centimeters in height and they use the eyes of the mosquitos to build small shields and protective masks.

Extra detail
They have access to the type of technology that Columbus had access to (compasses, knots etc.) and they live with the wildlife of late Pleistocene (to justify the fact that there's megafauna in the story)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific on how this tiny species would use a compound eye for equipment?  Or you want equipment that resembles a compound eye similar to that of a mosquito?  And I'm a little confused about the medieval nomadic explorer air-ship part tied in with Late Pleistocene.

Comment: Well if you're looking for criticism... Firstly it would be nice if you capitalized the starts of your sentences (avoids someone else having to do it for you via edit). Secondly as bumpy states, perhaps you could make your setting clearer. Are you asking about how tiny people could use mosquito eyes? How small are these beings?

Comment: They’re cool domes for light wells on the airship. Or porthole covers. Or nice bowls for dinner centerpieces.

Comment: I'll hopefully capitalize better on my next answer; thank you for notifying me.

Comment: You'd get a better answer by stripping out the "scenario" parts and asking biology.SE what (African, if it makes a difference) mosquitoes see through their compound eyes.  Then use that info to answer your WB question.

Comment: Are you looking for possible tools (you can make your made up people act irrational of course) or are you looking for tools those eyes are a better solution than more conventional approaches? Btw you have answered your own question, they make shields and masks with them.